# insert php value inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have this command inside my javascript to create a cookie with a specific value.

```
...
    document.cookie="superpage=John Doe;secure=true";
...
```

My goal: I want the content of this cookie inserted via PHP.

So I tried this: In a separate PHP file i declared

```
$myvalue = "superpage=John Doe;secure=true";
```

Then I changed the javascript cookie creation to this:

```
    ...
document.cookie= '<?php echo $myvalue; ?>';
...
```

Cookie is then created but with the value `<?php echo $myvalue` and not the string I defined via PHP. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In which file is located your javascript? It seems it is not processed by php

Comment: can you alert or console.log that $myvalue? alert(<?php echo $myvalue; ?>); or console.log(<?php echo $myvalue; ?>); if cannot it means your php file is not included to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your JavaScript on a page with `.php` extension and your code will work, .i.e:

**file.php**

```
<?php
$myvalue = "superpage=John Doe;secure=true";
?>
```

then, on the same page, outside the php block:

```
<script>
document.cookie= '<?php echo $myvalue; ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: Good to ear that! If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the correct answer. Tks.

Comment: @user3909280 to accept the answer you'll need to click on the check mark in the middle of the arrows ;)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be confusion on how to mix php with javascript. The only way to do so would be with javascript inside a php file:

```
<?php

php code.....

$myvalue = "superpage=John Doe;secure=true";

echo '
<script>
javascript code....
document.cookie= '.$myvalue.'
</script>';

?>
```